# Getting property overridden error for dataVersion() in SPFx

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

In spfx when I load the default reactjs template, I get this

[image]

Anyone know whats wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have probably solved this in the meantime, but for others coming across this post like I did today:

This seems to be an issue with the latest TypeScript Version that might have probably been updated.

Details here:
https://dreamsof.dev/2020-09-21-typescript-upgrade-breaking-dataversion-get-override-spfx11/

And in short:

Either fix it by using an older version of TypeScript

Within Visual Studio Code; press [F1] -> type “TypeScript” -> select “TypeScript: Select TypeScript version…”

or add ts-ignore on top of the code:

```
  // @ts-ignore
  protected get dataVersion(): Version {
    return Version.parse('1.0');
  }
```

Comment: Using the older version of typescript (v3 or 3.3) should fix it, but this ts-ignore is a good temp workaround.